# What is the name for the brush to clean this humidifier valve on my HVAC

Tags: hvac, basement, pipe, valve, humidifier

(Context) The previous owners put a humidifier on the HVAC and I could have sworn that the red wire thing attached to the valve had a brush on the end of it when I was with the inspector months ago. It is getting close to winter and I thought I'd try out the humidifier, but there is all that gunk in the valve.

(Question 1) Can I find a brush to clean to it out at Home Depot? I am not sure what to look for.

(Question 2) I am also not sure of how to clean it out. Do I open that red cap and push it out the other end? Do I need a cleaning solution or water? I am not sure what that thing with the wires does :/

(Question 3) Do I need to cover the valve that is holding my busted trap brush? It is exposed to air, I can't find a cap anywhere, and pictures online show that valve without a cap.

(Question 4) My trap is very dirty, I just shined a flashlight on it, is it safe to flush it with a bleach/water mixture? What about isopropyl alcohol?

[image: Picture of humidifier valve on HVAC]

Comment: The black cap with two black wires looks like a level sensor, to shut down the system when there's an overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a drain, not a supply line.

The device with the wires is an [EZ Trap Condensate Overflow Cut-Off Switch](http://m.homedepot.com/p/EZ-Trap-Condensate-Overflow-Cut-Off-Switch-EZT-225/203566285?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-AllProducts%7c&gclid=CKfQ0pqcg9ACFYNEhgodNdMMbg&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Here's a similar [device that includes a trap brush](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BMUFSGI).

Here's just a [trap brush](http://www.supplyhouse.com/EZ-Trap-83406-18-EZT-406-Standard-Flexible-Rod-Cleaning-Brush).